# Separation of responsibilities php for controllers

Tags: php, laravel, structure

So I use Laravel for my website, but I'm having trouble judging the structure of my code, so I'd like some input on the validity of my structure.

I of course use routing via Controllers, a request comes in, and this is routed to a `Processor`, this processor also receives a listener (the controller) which the processor uses to route again. An example

```
class PageController{
    public function __construct(PageProcessor $pageProcessor)
    {
        $this->processor = $pageProcessor;
    }
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->processor->edit($this, $id);
    }
    public function editFailed($message)
    {   
        return View::make('edit.failed', $message);
    }
    public function editSucceed($data)
    {
        return View::make('edit.succeed', $data);
    }
}
class PageProcessor{
    public function __construct(PageRepository $pageRepository, PageValidator $pageValidator)
    {
        $this->repository   = $pageRepository;
        $this->validator    = $pageValidator;
    }
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        // logic for showing the edit page
        //
        // more logic

        if($logicSucceeded)
        {
            return $listener->editSucceed(compact('page', 'awesomeData'));
        }
        else
        {
            return $listener->editFailed('something failed');
        }
    }

}
```

Now my problem is with the passing of the controller to the processor, kind of defeats the separation of responsibilities, but I cant think of another way of doing this.

To summarise: What is the best way to keep the responsibilities of classes which are entangled in each other?

How can I have one use the other without it knowing how it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, having logic for showing the edit page on the page processor may make you mix reponsibilities at some point. Looking from here your code is very good, skinny controllers and business logic outside controllers. But I would bring the views back to the controller:

```
class PageController {

    public function __construct(PageProcessor $pageProcessor)
    {
        $this->processor = $pageProcessor;
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->processor->validate($id, Input::all());

        $data = $this->processor->getEditData($id);

        return View::make('edit', compact('data'));
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $this->processor->update($data);

        // If the update fails, an exception will be thrown and it will never reach this return

        return Redirect::back();
    }

    public function editFailed($message)
    {   
        return View::make('edit.failed', $message);
    }

    public function editSucceed($data)
    {
        return View::make('edit.succeed', $data);
    }
}
```

The processor would be responsible only for data processing and throwing error messages:

```
class PageProcessor {

    public function __construct(PageRepository $pageRepository, PageValidator $pageValidator)
    {
        $this->repository   = $pageRepository;
        $this->validator    = $pageValidator;
    }

    public function getEditData($id)
    {
        return $this->repository->getData($id);
    }

    public function update($data)
    {
        if($updatedModel = $this->repository->update($data['id'], $data))
        {
            $listener->editSucceed(compact('page', 'awesomeData'));

            throw new Exception("Error Updating Model");
        }

        $listener->editFailed('something failed');

        return $updatedModel;
    }

    public function validate($id, $input)
    {
        if ($this->repository->validation->fails($id, $input))
        {
            throw new Exception("Validation failed", $this->repository->validation->errors());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

There's a consesus that validation should be triggered in the controller, or even before it, as in Laravel 4.3, so I added it to the controller method too.

EDIT:

The consensus lies in the fact that processing user input is a controller's responsibility. Of course sometimes there's more than just know if an email is well formed, sometimes your business logic depends on other factors, but now we are talking about two different types of validation: input data and business data. There's a good explanation for that in meta: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/in-mvc-should-a-model-handle-validation.

In Laravel 4.3 input data will be processed by your controllers, actually during controller instantiation:

So you'll see controllers being done like this:

```
public function store(AddOfficeRequest $request)
{
    $this->execute(AddOfficeCommand::class, $input);

    Flash::message('Office created');

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

That `AddOfficeRequest` will be

```
use use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AddOfficeRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'contact' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }

}
```

And the result of this is your controller `store` method only being hit **if input validation passes**, otherwise Laravel will automagically `Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors()`.

Comment: validation in the controller just seems like blasphemy, Isnt that supposed to be business logic? My processor is the one that brings validation and the model together, and for example creates the table.. could you elaborate ont he validation in the controller?>

Comment: I have adopted this pattern of making the processor only do data processing. It seperates it from the controller so that you can better use it in other situations. Thanks!

I find it hard to find good resources on these subjects

Answer (score 1):

The rules of OOP aren't, I think, as strict as you're making them out to be. Yes, separation of responsibilities calls for creating generalizable classes, and that's one reason to break some logic out into its own class.

But, for instance you *could* have written `PageController` with the `PageProcessor` logic inside it. Maybe that was just unwieldy code. It's also not a bad thing to create any number of classes with **specific** responsibilities, that are only referenced in one other class - especially if you think the `PageProcessor` might be used by another class in the future.